# Combining two handlers into one and executing them in a sequence

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, asynchronous, promise

I have two handlers that I want to combine into one, one of which is a handler that creates a user in firebase, and the other stores additional user information.

This creates a user in Firebase Authentication

```
authHandler = () => {
  const authData = {
      email: this.state.controls.email.value,
      password: this.state.controls.password.value
  };
  this.props.onTryAuth(authData, this.state.authMode);
};
```

This stores user information in Firebase Storage

```
userDataHandler = () => {
  this.props.onAddUserData(
     this.state.controls.userName.value
  )
};
```

I want to be able to combine both handlers but have it so that it executes asynchronously (i.e. authHandler first then userDataHandler). I hope I'm using the terminology correctly ><

Been racking my brain for the past few days but can't seem to figure it out. Was wondering if one of you guys/gals can explain to me how should I be tackling this problem. Thanks in advance.

Edit 1 Component

```
class SignUp extends Component {
    state = {
        controls: {
            email: {
                value: "",
                valid: false,
                validationRules: {
                isEmail: true
            },
            touched: false
        }, ... etc

updateInputState = (key, value) => {
    let connectedValue = {};
    if (this.state.controls[key].validationRules.equalTo) {
        const equalControl = this.state.controls[key].validationRules.equalTo;
        const equalValue = this.state.controls[equalControl].value;
        connectedValue = {
            ...connectedValue,
            equalTo: equalValue
        };
    }
    if (key === 'password') {
        connectedValue = {
            ...connectedValue,
            equalTo: value
        };
    }
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
            controls: {
                ...prevState.controls,
                confirmPassword: {
                    ...prevState.controls.confirmPassword,
                    valid: key === 'password' ? validate(
                        prevState.controls.confirmPassword.value, 
                        prevState.controls.confirmPassword.validationRules, 
                        connectedValue
                        ) 
                        :prevState.controls.confirmPassword.valid
                },
                [key]: {
                    ...prevState.controls[key],

                    value: value,
                    valid: validate(value, prevState.controls[key].validationRules, connectedValue), touched: true
                }
            }
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your title correctly, you want to execute these 2 function *synchronously*, as in one after another, correct? It sounds kind of counter-intuitive, but synchronous execution actually means the code waits for the previous block to finish executing before it itself is executed. Asynchronous execution means that the two blocks of code can be executing at the same time, which in your case, may lead to race conditions.

Anyways, to answer your question, React (and Javascript), has a simple way of handing a block of code that you requires completion of another block before it itself executes: [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You can try something like this

```
authAndUserDataHandler = () => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    const authData = {
      email: this.state.controls.email.value,
      password: this.state.controls.password.value
    };
    this.props.onTryAuth(authData, this.state.authMode);
  })
  .then((/*returned data from resolved promise*/)=>{
    this.props.onAddUserData(
      this.state.controls.userName.value
   )
  })
  .catch((/*returned error if promise rejects*/)=>{
    /*do something if the initial block of code in the promise rejects/fails*/
})
```

Comment: You're right aha. I am trying to execute the functions synchronously. I tried your suggestion from above, but it gave me an error saying that it 'Cannot read property of 'controls' of undefined'

Comment: Did it specify where the error is? The snippet above should work if it's in the same component as the 2 functions you provided.

Comment: The error is with 'controls' within the email: this.state.controls etc.

Comment: Hmmmm, the error indicates that this.state is not defined. Can you provide the rest of the component?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds silly but the rest of the component is about 300 lines ay, and I want to be helpful and only give you the parts that you need. I've shared the sections directly related to the state above. Hopefully it helps ><

Comment: Your state seems to be set up correctly, I don't see a reason for this not to be working. Maybe you can pass in this.state into function itself when you call it.